# Implementing own javaScriptConsoleMessage stops dev web inspector from working

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, web-inspector

I have a dialog with a QWebView and a hidden dev web inspector. I have subclassed QWebPage to reimplement javaScriptConsoleMessage to show the inspector when a JS error occurs. However, when I reimplement javaScriptConsoleMessage, the inspector stops working - it's blank.

```
class WebPage(QWebPage):
    """ Makes it possible to use a Python logger to print javascript console messages """
    def __init__(self, logger=None, parent=None):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__(parent)
        if not logger:
            logger = logging
            self.logger = logger

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, lineNumber, sourceID):
        self.logger.warning("JS " + sourceID + ":" + unicode(lineNumber) + "\n" + msg)
        # code here to reveal inspector
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I don't have any issues with this in my project. What versions of Qt and PyQt is this on? Can you share a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I inherited the GUI, and my Qt is not remotely good enough to produce such an example, I'm afraid. I'll try to add more elements relating to the problem - the WebPage and inspector instances.